# Mapbox iOS Condition Expression using MGL_MATCH

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-ios

Consider the following expression:

```
    NSExpression(
    layer.property = NSExpression(
      format: "MGL_MATCH(category, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@)",
      "restaurant", UIColor.red,
      "office", UIColor.blue,
      UIColor.black)
```

This will use the key path: 'category' to handle match. Is it possible to use multiple key paths?

For example:

```
    NSExpression(
    layer.property = NSExpression(
      format: "MGL_MATCH(category OR secondary_category, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@)",
      "restaurant", UIColor.red,
      "office", UIColor.blue,
      UIColor.black)
```

How do I make this work using Mapbox SDK?